How to reestablish connection with Databricks Connect
I'm using Databricks Connect to supply data to a web app built with Dash. My use case is similar to this example: https://github.com/databricks-demos/dbconnect-examples/tree/main/python/Plotly
After a certain amount of inactivity, I get the following GRPC exception:
Exception: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
details = "BAD_REQUEST: session_id is no longer usable. Generate a new session_id by detaching and reattaching the compute and then try again. (requestId=7e1394be-cf27-47d0-9c6a-f176af85522a)"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"BAD_REQUEST: session_id is no longer usable. Generate a new session_id by detaching and reattaching the compute and then try again

I think that the session is expiring, but I'm not sure how to reestablish the connection without restarting the entire app.
I've tried the following commands:
    spark.stop()
    spark.newSession()
    spark = DatabricksSession.builder.serverless().getOrCreate()

But when I call spark.newSession() I get:
pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkAttributeError: [JVM_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_SUPPORTED] Attribute `newSession` is not supported in Spark Connect as it depends on the JVM. If you need to use this attribute, do not use Spark Connect when creating your session. Visit  for creating regular Spark Session in detail.https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession

Any ideas on how to restore the Databricks Connect session from within the Dash app? Thank you!

The solution is in the error message :  Visit this link to find out how to do what you are trying to do : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession

Thanks for the reply @easleyfixed. I did take a look at the link before posting, but I'm using databricks serverless compute and not sure how to connect to that with SparkSession since authentication with databricks and configuration is handled through the Databricks CLI

Hmm I wish I knew the answer for you on that, but unfortunatley its claiming you can't do it with PySpark so it seems you need to find another way than that.

Gotcha, well thanks for the help

I wonder if there is a way to increase the Session Timeout to make them last longer, or is it possibe that what ever action you doing when this triggers is causing it to manually terminate the connection.  Hopefully its the former.  Good luck!

@CarsonGrose why do you need spark.newSession()?  Should stoping and calling getOrCreate not create a new session?

Yes you are correct. I found that the issue had to do with the way that Dash stores the spark session between callback functions. So it ended up being more of an issue with how Dash works than with Databricks Connect
